# Determining minimum width of irregular polygon with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, dimensions, min

I would like to determinate minimum width of an irregular polygon (as those in red in picture) with PyQGIS. Does anyone have any advice?

[image]

Comment: @BERA I edited previous picture for a better understanding

Comment: Maybe you coul find something usefull in the [QgsGeometry class](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsGeometry.html), maybe...

Comment: There is a prior issue of definition. How to distinguish between between width and e.g. cutting a corner. For example, one could fit an "In Circle" (maximum radius circle) through which any line must pass to be considered crossing the width of the polygon, then find the shortest path between vertices which does that.

Comment: @AnserGIS I'm not sure I understood. How can I create maximum radius circle if I don't have the radius a prior?